# salesforce oauth authorization

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I am trying to access my Salesforce account from my web service.

In application settings I have added right callback URI.
I am going to: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=3MVG9HxRZv05HarRSLB9DXXecYwIjvp5bTXOSgJDeX7rfqxNj1AshD3hy.OksG0ozEVmNEKrbchW21qna0dmC&response_type=code&scope=full&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmy.callback.uri&state=udhdHud537hdHjsv4h

But I am receiving: `error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration`

What's wrong with the configuration?

Comment: When you enabled Oauth settings for your app you have to supply the redirect uri. While making the call use the same url that you used while configures Oauth settings.